# How to get a specific value from json with similar tags with T-SQL

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

I have a `nvarchar(max)` column with a json blob structured like this:

```
[
    {"QuestionName":"Question1", "AnswerValue":"123456"},
    {"QuestionName":"Question2", "AnswerValue":"987654"},
    {"QuestionName":"Question3", "AnswerValue":"951753"}
]
```

I would like to do this in a set based operation as I am pulling back over 50k records. I would like to get the Answer Value `where QuestionName = Question2`.

In the case above I'd like to return 987654. This value may not be in the exact same place of the array every time.

I am very green when working with JSon, let alone using it in SQL Server. I believe what I want is something like

```
JSON_VALUE(MyJSonColumn, '???')
```

but I'm not sure how to actually get what I need.

Comment: [This portion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#convert-json-collections-to-a-rowset) of the Microsoft docs seems to cover your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `OPENJSON`:

```
SELECT a.questionName, a.answerValue
FROM t 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(col)
WITH(QuestionName VARCHAR(100) N'$."QuestionName"', AnswerValue INT N'$."AnswerValue"') AS a
WHERE questionName = 'Question2';
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8c9762c41b70060ba74131174d6949b8)**